# How to update Oracle ODBC driver in Windows and all existing ODBC sources

Tags: windows, oracle, oracle11g, odbc

I would like to update Oracle ODBC driver on Windows 2008 R2 64bit Machine from version 11.2.0.1 to 11.2.0.4. 
I downloaded from http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/topics/winx64soft-089540.html: (version 11.2.0.4)

- Instant Client Package - Basic
- Instant Client Package - ODBC: Additional libraries for enabling ODBC applications

Then unzipped two files, merged them into one folder and then from CMD line with administrative privileges run script:

```
odbc_install
```

Then I was able to see the driver on the list in ODBC driver in 'Microsoft ODBC Administrator'.

The problem is that I would like that all exsting configured System DSN which use 11.2.0.1 Oracle driver should be updated with 11.2.0.4 version.

Could you please advise me what steps I should take to achieve it.

Best regards
Daniel

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it directly in your Registry. ODBC Drivers are located at:

```
HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Wow6432Node\ODBC\ODBCINST.INI\{Oracle Home Name}\Driver    
HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\ODBC\ODBCINST.INI\{Oracle Home Name}\Driver
```

Check and update following values:

```
HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\ODBC\ODBC.INI\{Your DNS Entry}\Driver    
HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Wow6432Node\ODBC\ODBC.INI\{Your DNS Entry}\Driver    
HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\ODBC\ODBC.INI\{Your DNS Entry}\Driver
```

Comment: Thanks. It was very helpful, but i have about 50 DSNs and need to prepare 'regedit' script that modify all desired entries

Comment: Export the ODBC branches and modify the file with a text editor. Then you can import it again.

Comment: Just to add to this: The values under HKEY_CURRENT_USER can override those in set under  HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE.  And note that you need administrative privileges to change values under HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE but this is not necessary for HKEY_CURRENT_USER.